# How to start and stop an Orleans cluster

Tags: c#, .net-core, orleans

I'm running an Orleans cluster locally. I've plugged in Orleans to my .NET Core Web API, as per the standard recommendations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/tutorials-and-samples/tutorial-1).

Everything runs just fine, but when I'm developing and repeatedly start my web api in the debugger (Rider IDE) and then stop, every other time I get an error during startup that says: `Denying connection to known-dead silo...`

Looking through the documentation, the extension method [UseConsoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/configuration-guide/shutting-down-orleans) is recommended for shutdown. But when I run it it throws a `NotSupportedException`, referencing me to use the 'regular' appBuilder.Build() instead. I've also tried `UseConsoleLifetime()`, but no luck.

**So to my question:** I can always run a hosted service that simply starts and stops my cluster, but how do I do that? I mean, how can I defer starting and stopping the cluster to my hosted service? What methods do I need to invoke? As it is now it seems like the cluster is auto-starting when I run the Web API.

I'm looking for explicitly controlling startup/shutdown.

Comment: Add a code how you co-host api and silo. I co-host asp.net core and orleans and it works just fine locally.